# Does Amazon Cloudformation support SWF domains, workflow types and activity types?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-swf

I am struggling to find any documentation or examples of a cloudformation template for a SWF domain, workflow types and activity types.

Comment: AWS SWF has been kind of deprecated but not really. Might be time to swap over.

Comment: AWS Step Functions was created by the same team that owns Amazon Simple Workflow. Step Functions is the modern take on workflow, although SWF is pretty good when used with Lambda functions.